# Java scanner: line separator is not recognized as an input

Tags: java

I have a `Test` class that creates a `Scanner` and reads a user's input. I want to recognize when a user pressed `Enter`, so I check if the next symbol of the input equals to `lineSeparator`. However, even though I do press `Enter` it doesn't get recognized as such.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (reader.next().equals(System.lineSeparator()))  {
                    System.out.println("finished");
            }

            /but at the same time, this one works as expected:
            String temp = "dog" + System.lineSeparator() + "cat";
            System.out.println(temp);
}
}
```

At the same time when I construct a string using `lineSeparator`, it works fine, adding a new line as expected.

What is wrong here and how to recognize if a user pressed `Enter`?

Comment: "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace". [Read the docs, perhaps?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: The newline character is a delimiter by default, which means it won't actually be returned by `next()` or `nextLine()`.

Comment: use nextLine() instead of next() and u dont need to have lineSeperator in that case.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to use hasNextLine() to check if nextline exists and then nextLine() to read the nextLine. Something like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
```